# How to retrieve post id to pass through Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Let's say I have a website like Facebook, Twitter, or any social network. I have posts in a feed. I retrieve a list of data about each post from the backend. This data contains the `id, post description, number of likes, etc.` The unique `id` is a way to identify each post.

I have a REST framework set up where if the user likes the post; it updates the likes count of that post and registers the user as he/he liked that post. For this to happen, I need to make an AJAX request on `localhost/like/{post_id}`

How can I get the id of the post? Should I put this id in a `data-attribute` in the like button and that way I can retrieve the id like this? If this is the case, should I put the id in all the actionable features (like button, dislike button, share button, etc.)?
Here's what my post's button container looks like:

```
        <div class="grid post__btn-container">
            <div class="item">
                <i class="like"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <i class="dislike"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <i class="share"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <i class="comment"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What is the best way to place the post id and get it and pass it as a POST request in Ajax?

Comment: The best way in this specific case is the way that works for you

Comment: @AlonEitan is the way I am describing a valid approach is there an easier or better way of doing this?

Comment: I used this approach for several times in the past, in my opinion it is a valid approach (as long as you validate the important things on the server side, and not trusting the client input before the validation)

Comment: @AlonEitan just to make sure, you've put the id in each buttons data attribute? So like each button has a data attribute with the post's id?

Comment: I would prefer to set it on the parent (`grid post__btn-container`) easyer to handle IMO, but I really don't think that in this particular scenario there is a right or wrong answer

Comment: @AlonEitan Hmm, but lets say the user likes that post. We have multiple posts on the page, how can I get just that post's id from the container whenever someone likes a specific post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this:

https://jsfiddle.net/x5m7j0Lk/

Given a setup like this

```
    <div class="grid post__btn-container" data-postid="123">
        <div class="item">
            <i class="like">Like</i>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <i class="dislike">Dislike</i>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <i class="share">Share</i>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <i class="comment">Comment</i>
        </div>
    </div>        
    <div class="grid post__btn-container" data-postid="456">
        <div class="item">
            <i class="like">Like</i>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <i class="dislike">Dislike</i>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <i class="share">Share</i>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <i class="comment">Comment</i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can retrieve the id like this:

```
var posts = $('div[class="grid post__btn-container"]').children()

posts.on("click", function(){
  var postId = $(this).parent().data('postid')
  alert(postId)
})
```